# Delete all information or delete row

Tags: javascript

**MY JAVASCRIPT CODE:**

```
var a1=1;

function addst(data)
{
    var table = document.getElementById('student');
    var rowCount = table.rows.length;
    var row =  table.insertRow(rowCount);
    row.innerHTML = '&nbsp;';
    for(i=0;i<3;i++)
        {   
            var row = table.insertRow(rowCount+i+1);
            row.innerHTML = table.rows[i].innerHTML;    
            if(i==0)
            {
                row.id="st"+a1+"";
            }
        }       
    count++;
}

function addRow(data)
{
    var table = document.getElementById('student');
    var rowCount = table.rows.length;
    var row =  table.insertRow(rowCount);
    row.innerHTML = '&nbsp;';
    for(i=0;i<3;i++)
        {   
            var row = table.insertRow(rowCount+i+1);
            row.innerHTML = table.rows[i].innerHTML;    
            if(i==0)
            {
                row.id="st"+a1+"";
            }
        }       
    count++;
} 

function deleteRow(data) 
{
    var table = document.getElementById('student');
    var rowCount = table.rows.length;
        var p=data.parentNode.parentNode;
        p.parentNode.removeChild(p);
}
```

**MY HTML CODE**

```
<fieldset>
<legend align="center">Student Information</legend> 
<br>
<table id="student">
    <tr id="s1">        
        <th><select name="" width="250px"> 
        <option value="" selected align="center">student Type</option>
        <option value="">male</option>
        <option value="">female</option>
        </select></th>
        <th><input type="button" value="+" onclick="addst(this)"/>
        <th><input type="button" value="-" onclick="delst(this)"/>
    </tr>

    <tr id="label">
        <th align="left">class info</th>
        <th align="left">Math</th>
        <th align="left">Phy</th>
        <th align="left">Chem</th>
        <th align="left">Total</th>
        <th align="left">Average</th>   
    </tr>
    <tr id="c1">
        <td>
            <select> 
                <option value="" selected>Select your class</option>
                <option>8</option>
                <option>9</option>
                <option>10</option>
                <option>11</option>
            </select>
        </td>

        <td><input type="text" id="val02" size="16" name="math" placeholder="Math marks"/></td>
        <td><input type="text" id="val03" size="16" name="phy" placeholder="Phy marks"/></td>
        <td><input type="text" id="val04" size="16" name="chem" placeholder="Chem marks"/></td>
        <td><input type="text" id="val06" size="16" name="total" placeholder="Total marks"/></td>
        <td><input type="text" id="val07" size="16" name="avg" placeholder="Average marks"/></td>
        <th><input type="button" value="+"  id="r1" onclick="addRow(this)" /></th>          
        <th><input type="button" value="-"  id="r1" onclick="delRow(this)" /></th>
    </tr>
</TABLE>
</fieldset>
```

The ***'addst'*** and ***'addRow'*** functions are working but have no idea how delete functions should be written.

***'delst'*** should delete the whole respective student information while ***'delRow'*** should delete the each individual row.

Comment: Have you tried anything for `delRow` function?

Comment: Sorry delRow is working. but delst is not working
I will add delRow code to it

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to do. Your addst and addRow functions are identical... so wouldn't your delst be identical to your delRow? I'm really not understanding what the goal is.